# Counting sequential dates in R to determine the length of an event

Tags: r, date, sequence

I have a dataframe containing dates when a given event occurred. Some events go on for several days, and I want to summarise each event based on its start date and its total length (in days).

I want to go from this:

| Date |
| --- |
| 2020-01-01 |
| 2020-01-02 |
| 2020-01-03 |
| 2020-01-15 |
| 2020-01-20 |
| 2020-01-21 |

To this:

| StartDate | EventLength |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 3 |
| 2020-01-15 | 1 |
| 2020-01-20 | 2 |

I've tried various approaches with *aggregate*, *ave*, *seq_along* and *lag*, but I haven't managed to get a count of event length that resets when the dates aren't sequential.

Code for the example data frame in case it's helpful:

```
Date <- c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-15", "2020-01-20", "2020-01-21")
df <- data.frame(Date)
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, origin = "1970-01-01")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `split` by `cumsum(c(0, diff(df$Date) != 1)` and then take the first date and combine it with the `length` assuming the *dates are sorted*.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df$Date, cumsum(c(0, diff(df$Date) != 1))),
  function(x) data.frame(StartDate=x[1], EventLength=length(x))))
#   StartDate EventLength
#0 2020-01-01           3
#1 2020-01-15           1
#2 2020-01-20           2
```

or another option using `rle`:

```
i <- cumsum(c(0, diff(df$Date) != 1))
data.frame(StartDate = df$Date[c(1, diff(i)) == 1], EventLength=rle(i)$lengths)
#   StartDate EventLength
#1 2020-01-01           3
#2 2020-01-15           1
#3 2020-01-20           2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution with a `cumsum` trick followed by `ave/table`.

```
d <- c(0, diff(df$Date) != 1)
res <- ave(df$Date, cumsum(d), FUN = function(x) x[1])
res <- as.data.frame(table(a))
names(res) <- c("Date", "EventLength")

res
#        Date EventLength
#1 2020-01-01           3
#2 2020-01-15           1
#3 2020-01-20           2
```

Answer (score 2):

I propose `dplyr` approach which is incidentally very similar to @Rui's approach

```
df %>% mutate(dummy = c(0, diff(Date))) %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(dummy != 1)) %>%
  summarise(Date = first(Date),
            event_count = n(), .groups = 'drop')

# A tibble: 3 x 3
    grp Date       event_count
  <int> <date>           <int>
1     1 2020-01-01           3
2     2 2020-01-15           1
3     3 2020-01-20           2
```

Comment: How would i combine this to make event number in ascending order with criteria in the group_by? Like first date = 1 and second -=2 for one specific id.

Comment: @PotterFan, you may add one more line with `arrange`